# MySQL: Select query using WHERE IN () with variables on the basis of conditions

Tags: mysql, select, procedure, where-in

For my MySQL `PROCEDURE`, I have a select query statement using `WHERE IN (...)` clause, for which I need some conditional inputs/variables.

example:

```
SELECT * FROM test_table tt WHERE tt.section IN ('A', 'B', 'C');

SELECT * FROM test_table tt WHERE tt.section IN ('A', 'B', 'D');

SELECT * FROM test_table tt WHERE tt.section IN ('A','C');

SELECT * FROM test_table tt WHERE tt.section IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D');
```

How can I achieve this using a single query?

Note: This select query statement is inside mySQL `PROCEDURE`.

---

I'm looking for something like this:

```
SET @ABC = '"A", "B", "C"';
SET @ABCD = '"A", "B", "C", "D"';
SET @AC = '"A", "B", "C", "D"';

SET @IN_CLAOUSE_VARIABLES = NULL;

IF (<CONDITION 1>) THEN
    SET @IN_CLAOUSE_VARIABLES = @ABC;
  ELSEIF (<CONDITION 2>) THEN
    SET @IN_CLAOUSE_VARIABLES = @ABCD;
  ELSE
    SET @IN_CLAOUSE_VARIABLES = @AC;
END IF:

SELECT * FROM test_table tt WHERE tt.section IN (@IN_CLAOUSE_VARIABLES);
```

Comment: `WHERE tt.section IN ('A', 'B', 'C') OR tt.section IN ('A', 'B', 'D') ...`? [OR Clause](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/or.php#:~:text=)

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton - Thank you for you help. I'm looking for specific input for this query, where I can't use `OR` or `AND` condition.

Comment: `WHERE FIND_IN_SET(tt.section, 'A,B,C')`. The criteria array have single literal CSV form, not separate literals, with any values amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SET @ABC = 'A,B,C';
SET @ABCD = 'A,B,C,D';
SET @AC = 'A,C';

SET @IN_CLAOUSE_VARIABLES = NULL;

IF (<CONDITION 1>) THEN
    SET @IN_CLAOUSE_VARIABLES = @ABC;
  ELSEIF (<CONDITION 2>) THEN
    SET @IN_CLAOUSE_VARIABLES = @ABCD;
  ELSE
    SET @IN_CLAOUSE_VARIABLES = @AC;
END IF:

SELECT * FROM test_table tt WHERE FIND_IN_SET(tt.section, @IN_CLAOUSE_VARIABLES);
```

`tt.section` must NOT contain commas and not need to be quoted with `"`. I.e. it may be `'A'` (will be found in all variants), `'D'` (only when `<CONDITION 1>` is false and `<CONDITION 2>` is true) or `'X'` (never).